# Boot ubuntu from USB option not available?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, usb

So I followed the steps [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and downloaded *Ubuntu* onto my 32gb usb drive and I am trying to figure out how to boot up from the USB.

When I go to my boot menu on my laptop I get boot from notebook hard drive and boot from live cd/dvd. No option to boot from external hard drive. I went to my bios and added network boot to the options but none of those seemed like what I wanted to do so I didn't select those, i did not want to mess anything up.

My machine is an *HP x16-1025nr entertainment notebook PC* Current OS is *Windows Vista*.

### EDIT

I also have a blank CD, if anybody knows how to boot from a blank CD I will try that too.

I have a program on it to download the **.iso* to the disk , it says mounting image, but when I boot from CD nothing happens it goes straight to *Windows Vista* which makes me think the image was not mounted correctly. I don't really care which way, USB or CD I just want it to work without wiping my hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "boot from the hard drive" option. On my computer I do that, it then shows two options, one for the internal hard drive and one for the USB. Try and feed me back

oh yes, you should be using the boot menu in the first place. sorry, forgot to say that. you should find an instruction to press some button (normally del or f11 or f12), you should see something like "press del for boot menu" right after you start your computer.

Comment: There was no option shown, I did boot from notebook hard drive and vista booted right up, no option to choose, I don't think it is reading my usb until vista turns on. My usb has a flashing light when stuff happens to it and it doesn't turn on until vista starts running.

Comment: okay did you boot by using the boot menu option? or by setting "boot order priorities"?

Comment: I pressed esc while it was booting up, then a menu came up and I pressed f9 which was boot menu options. There i did boot from notebook hard drive. After i went to the bios and I set the priority to check for usb BEFORE the notebook hard drive and the same thing happened when i went to boot options.

Comment: hmmmm. well I _think_ the notebook can't recognize the usb as bootable. you should see an option to boot from it. you can try connecting the USB to other USB ports! this might make it work. However if that fails, another way of installing Ubuntu is using CD!! yes you can do that! did you try using these instuctions http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows ?

Comment: I didn't use that one. I went into my USB, which is now called "Install ubuntu" after all that past usb stuff,  and used wubi from it. A menu came up to demo it from CD, "to start the live CD you need to reboot your machine leaving the CD in the tray" and an option to reboot. I did that and nothing happened it went straight to vista. Im not sure if it thinks the USB is a cd, or it knows i have a cd in the tray. I am going to try your link this time and see what happens.

Comment: well okay. ... I just wanna make sure; when trying to install Ubuntu from the CD, after you got the reboot message and rebooted the computer, did you _either_ set the boot priority to CD first _or_ use the boot menu option?? ... (from what you're saying, the CD looks fine to boot from)

Comment: AH YES. I used the boot option menu and did the livecd/dvd option and it worked! Its pretty lame that my machine can't read USBs but whatever doesn't matter now. Thank you :D

Comment: so you got it working!!! great :D you're welcome :D

Comment: ...oh, would you mark this question as the accepted question (hit the check button under the arrows) so that people who have the same question would know where the answer is. and you might wanna upvote it as well. -this gives me points XD-

Answer (score 1):

My USB stick was detected as a removable HDD, so instead of a removable device see if a flash drive has been added to your list of hard disks to boot from in the bios.(while it is plugged in)

If not try F11 for a manual boot menu (my Asus Mother board has this option).

To burn an ISO to a CD, don't just drag it to the CD, this will only put the file on the CD, use Nero/IMG burn or which ever is your profered CD writing software and 'Burn disk image' this will unpack the ISO onto the CD and create a bootable disk.
Im sure that from win 7 upwards right clicking will give the option to 'burn image' also

The Ubuntu website has a step by step guide for creating a bootable CD.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

the boot priority order remains the same make sure that CD-rom is higher than HDD and it will boot from the CD

Comment: The usb is not in the bios menu, also f11 is hard drive recovery or something

Comment: then 'Del' or 'F2' should take you into Bios. pressing 'esc' will cancel the memcheck and procede to the first boot choice you see. from bios there is an option to choose boot priority, which can be CD-rom, HDD USB/removable drive. sometimes USB sticks are classed as HDD's by Bois'. though where exactly the boot priority menu is is different per motherboard

Comment: choose an order that puts the flash drive, or CDrom ahead of the windows bootable HDD and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install *Ubuntu* OS from a blanck DVD, what you can do is to [download it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (as you probably already did), and [burn the **.iso* file onto the DVD using *Windows Vista*](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows).

If you have any other questions, please let us know.